# Why doesn't sequelize include associated model to a nested object in the results?

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two associated models: TariffsModel and PoliciesModel. PoliciesModel has tariff_id which refers to specific tariff by its ID. And this works but Sequelize returns the result in a weird way:
instead of returning:

```
PoliciesModel {
   id: 1,
   owner_party_id: 2,
   tariff: {
      id: 1,
      is_active: true,
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

it returns:

```
PoliciesModel {
   id: 1,
   owner_party_id: 2,
   tariff.id: 1,
   tariff.is_active: true,
   ...
}
```

Here's the example: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Qqb.png)

I initiate the relation like this:

```
const {
            PoliciesModel,
            TariffsModel,
        } = this.sequeluze.models;

        PoliciesModel.belongsTo(TariffsModel, { foreignKey: 'tariff_id', as: 'tariff' });
```

and make the query like this:

```
const policies = await PoliciesModel.findAll({
            where: { owner_party_id: userAccount.party_id },
            include: {
                model: TariffsModel,
                as: 'tariff',
            },
            raw: true,
        });
```

What could be the reason of this kind of behavior?

I tried calling hasMany/hasOne methods and using `as` parameter, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Sequelize query, if you remove the property **raw** then you get the response as expected.

```
const policies = await PoliciesModel.findAll({
            where: { owner_party_id: userAccount.party_id },
            include: {
                model: TariffsModel,
                as: 'tariff',
            }
        });
```

The query should be like the following one.